# Google Directory API user list request failing with 400 Invalid Input

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-directory-api

I'm trying to get a successful response when executing the request from https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list?apix_params=%7B%22customer%22%3A%22my_customer%22%7D. I'm getting a `400 Invalid Input` response.

With the client library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis, v47), when calling:

```js
google.admin('directory_v1')
  .users.list({
     auth: oAuth2Client,
     customer: 'my_customer',
     orderBy: 'email',
     maxResults: 500,
     pageToken: null
  }).then(...);
```

, I'm receiving a `Request` object in the success handler, instead of a valid response(response which should have had the shape described at the bottom of https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the authentication process, using the `google-auth-library`.
I've resorted to something like this:

```js
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const oAuthClient = await google.auth.getClient({keyFile: ..., scopes: [...]});
oAuthClient.credentials = await new google.auth.JWT(...).authorizeAsync();

const {data} = await google
  .admin({version: 'directory_v1', auth: oAuthClient})
  .users
  .list({
     customer: 'my_customer'
  });
```

Comment: @Chadd It appears in the auth library, https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/master/src/auth/jwtclient.ts.

Comment: I  am having similar problem as I am using a service account. But can't seem to find the reason. I posted a question as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717611/gsuite-service-account-for-directory-api-returns-http-400-errors-bad-request-in

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to get an example from the accepted answer working, so after experimenting with authentication methods, here's how to generate a valid bearer JWT for authenticating on behalf of the service account.

JSON passed to init `authClient` is what you get after generating a new key in Google Cloud > IAM & Admin > Service Accounts > Keys.

Here I'm getting a list of users from a directory, but after adjusting scopes it would be able to do pretty anything as it's whitelisted in Domain-Wide Delegation in Google Admin:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library');

const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'];
const subject = 'admin.email@your.domain.org';
const customerId = 'C91FjKp'; // update this with a valid Google Workspace customerId

async function main() {
  const authClient = await auth.fromJSON({
    "type": "service_account",  
    "project_id": "gam-project-aan-olo-dkr",
    "private_key_id": "73228246f4f6e8d0933d1d121dda0626cf590e45",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nzZAPFWjcPiQJ08jgWPm3FSIJ\nXthRo2VZSjxagJtSPKk3Jg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "gam-project-aan-olo-dkr@gam-project-aan-olo-dkr.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "101593547182107617346",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/gam-project-aan-olo-dkr%40gam-project-aan-olo-dkr.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  });
  authClient.scopes = scopes;
  authClient.subject = subject;

  const admin = google.admin({ version: 'directory_v1', auth: authClient });
  const res = await admin.users.list({
    customer: customerId,
    query: 'isSuspended=False',
    maxResults: 100,
    orderBy: 'email',
    viewType: 'admin_view',
    projection: 'basic',
    showDeleted: false,
    alt: 'json'
  });

  console.log(res.data);
}

main();
```

(all secrets and IDs in example are fake, use yours).