# gsuite service account for directory api returns http 400 errors: Bad request/Invalid input

Tags: python, google-api, service-accounts, http-error, google-directory-api

I have started to develop some apis to create users in my G suite directory.
I followed the [service account tutorials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) along with the [Directory tutorials](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python) for python. The code I have is very simple just to test out how it will work.

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'file'
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.users().list(customer='i am not sure what customer is', maxResults=10, orderBy='email').execute() 
#this line produces the error.
#Vscode also states the service has no member users. But I did install all #the libraries
users = results.get('users', [])
print(users)
```

The documentation to me is unclear about most things. When I run this I get

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=students&maxResults=10&orderBy=email&alt=json returned "Bad Request">
```

When I change customer from `my_customer` to something else I get `Invalid Input`.
Any suggestions to what may cause this error and preferably how to work with this api via a service account?
Now I did enable the `directory api` and create the service account and downloaded the service account file as well. Am I missing a step?
I would also prefer if someone has a better documentation that I was unable to find.

Comment: Hi, @sakib11. I have the same issue using Java, do you have a solution?

Comment: Okay so the issue is related to the scopes. Recheck your scopes from the Gsuite administration and also make sure that the customer can be 'me'.

Comment: So I revisited this, it is only a scope issue. Just go to your google admin security page and make sure that your delegated service account has the required scope.

Comment: Yes, it was related with the scopes. I also had to impersonate an admin account to  make it work. Thanks!

Comment: great thatit helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the service account has domain-wide-delegation enabled and has the proper scopes.

Answer (score 4):

Finally I resolved this issue by setting another parameter "subject" when calling "service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file".

Comment: For me, I didn't even know that a param like that even existed.

Comment: What was the subject you added?

Comment: @Europa subject equals to the email address of the admin, who will be actor for the action.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's pretty unclear how to do a basic thing if you want to craft a tiny helper script. JSON for a Service Account is what you get after generating a new key in Google Cloud > IAM & Admin > Service Accounts > Keys. Here's how the full final variant looks:

```
import json
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']
SUBJECT = 'admin.email@your.domain.org'
CUSTOMER_ID = 'C91FjKp'

def main():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        '/path/to/service-account-key.json', scopes=SCOPES
    )
    credentials = credentials.with_subject(SUBJECT)
    admin = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
    results = admin.users().list(
        customer=CUSTOMER_ID,
        query='isSuspended=False',
        maxResults=100,
        orderBy='email',
        viewType='admin_view',
        projection='basic',
        showDeleted=False,
    ).execute()
    print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```